# MySQL Spatial Data Type Indexing Performance Comparison

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial-index, spatial-query

Would a MBR function query against an indexed column with geometry type containing points and polygons (GeomCollection type) be slower than a MBR function against an indexed column with a polygon type?

My programmer instincts tell me that it would be slower and I should use the most descriptive spatial type I can.

Edit: After reading Denis's answer, the real question is:

In MySQL "does an indexed column with geometry type containing points and polygons actually contain the latter or are they reduced to a MBR?"

Comment: Sorry, but I really do not know. What is "MBR"?

Comment: Ah, "Minimum Bounding Rectangle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm risking an answer here, without being sure on the MySQL front...

But in Postgres, geometry types indexed using GIST will usually be [indexed as boxes](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/strange-bug-with-gist-over-box-and-circle-td2131182.html), a.k.a. MBR, irrespective of what whether they're circles, polygones, etc.

So the real question might be better rephrased as: "does an indexed column with geometry type containing points and polygons actually contain the latter or are they reduced to a MBR?"

Comment: @Nate: in that case, I'd hazard a yes. (I wouldn't be doing so if MySQL had wizards around that were better at using and optimizing R-tree indexes than the Postgres folks. But the fact is, they don't. Postgres offers Generalized Inverted Search Tree indexes *and* Generalized Inverted Indexes; both are better. The former, in PG 9.1, allows to leverage an index for k-nearest searches, something that MySQL isn't doing to date. And both work in an ACID compliant environment, whereas MySQL still requires MyISAM for spacial indexes.)

Comment: Okay, I thought that might be the case.